# How to compare each value with every other value in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark as shown below

```
  a    b
( 21 , 23 )
( 23 , 21 )
( 22 , 21 )
( 21 , 22 )
```

I want a dataframe which should look like this:-

```
( 21 , 22 )
( 21 , 23 )
( 22 , 21 )
( 22 , 23 )
( 23 , 21 )
( 23 , 22 )
```

So it should consider all possible combinations for both columns. How this can be achieved?

I tried Cartesian join but it is taking too much time for very small dataset.Any other alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
zip(*pairs_rdd).flatten.deduplicate.foreach(n => (n,n-1)).cache()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why your `join` is "taking too much time" without seeing your code. I find the following method works reasonably fast for me:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
    Row(a=21, b=22),
    Row(a=22, b=23),
  ]
)

# rename to avoid identical colume names in the result
df_copy = df.alias('df_copy')
df_copy = df_copy.withColumnRenamed('a', 'a_copy')
df_copy = df_copy.withColumnRenamed('b', 'b_copy')

df.join(df_copy, how='outer').select(df.a, df_copy.b_copy).collect()
```